# Unity - How to get data from a js script to a csharp script?

Tags: c#, facebook, unity-game-engine, sdk, unityscript

I have my player score located in the gameobject _GM (script = gamemaster.js) like this:

```
static var currentScore : int = 0;
```

Now I want this score to be used here:
(In the script gameOver.cs located in an other scene)

```
public void SetScore() {
        var scoreData = new Dictionary<string,string> ();
        scoreData ["score"] = THIS SHOULD BE THE CURRENTSCORE;
        FB.API ("/me/scores", Facebook.HttpMethod.POST, delegate (FBResult result) {
            Debug.Log ("Score submit result: " + result.Text);
        }, scoreData);
    }
```

So my game can post that data to Facebook.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have two scripts, especially when they're different langues, what you need to do is pay attention to the script compilation order.

So, what you need to do is this

- Place your .js file in either **Standard Assets**, **Pro Standard Assets**, or **Plugins**
- Place your .cs file in any folder **except** the ones listed above
- Now, in your .cs file, you can access the score "currentScore" as follows

  ```
  scoreData ["score"] = gamemaster.currentScore;
  ```

[Unity Manual - Script compilation order](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompileOrderFolders.html)

Comment: I moved my gamemaster.js file to the plugins folder. The problem I have now is that all the references to other scripts (the gamemaster.js is the script that holds the game together) are getting errors. I refer to other scripts like this: ScoreLane7.LaughScorePoint.

Comment: Move those scripts into the same folder as gamemaster.js. Problem solved

Comment: I cant because those scripts are working with a plugin that has to be compiled befor them. But I rewrote my gamemaster.js script so it no longer needs those scripts. Now I still get this small error: Cannot implicitly convert type `int' to `string' when I try to post the score to FB.

Comment: That's because your score variable is an integer. Change to gamemaster.currentScore.ToString()